# Has bandwidth usage or data transferred when mining or hosting a full node increased since the introduction of RingCT?

Tags: ringct, full-node, cpu-mining, mining, bandwidth

I've recently started hosting a handful of nodes on my home internet connection and mining to a pool from these machines, it seems as though my internet connection has become a lot slower and a lot of data has been used up.

It's possible that this is simply an issue with my ISP, but I wanted to find out if anyone knows the amount of data uploaded/downloaded when hosting a full node and when mining now that RingCT has been implemented. Have bandwidth and data transfer requirements increased?

I'm aware of the 'limit' command in monerod, which I have set to 100, but sometimes it still seems like the Monero nodes and mining processes are taking up a lot of bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, RingCT transactions are much bigger than non-RingCT transactions. The monthly blockchain growth [has already more than doubled](http://moneroblocks.info/stats#blockchain-growth) in comparison to December 2016, when RingCT hasn't been enabled yet.

Why are you hosting more than one full node at home? You just need one full node and all your local machines can connect to it via local network.

Comment: I'd heard that having more full nodes available was better for the Monero network, so I am hosting one on each of my spare machines at home.

Comment: It is in fact better to have more full nodes, but not if all of them share a limited connection and each one has to sync with the network. Better to have one full node, which has more bandwidth than several nodes with very limited bandwidth.

Comment: I will second what @pebx said, this is what led to the demise and eventual service cutoff with my internet service provider.  They sold me an unlimited plan and I had 10 full nodes of just about any coin worth mining.  Had I set up each node to sync with my 1 local node, then I'd have saved 9 times as much bandwidth as I used daily.

TLDR: run one node connected to the outside, the rest can sync locally