# Has bandwidth usage or data transferred when mining or hosting a full node increased since the "introduction of RingCT"?

Tags: bandwidth

I've recently started hosting a handful of nodes on my home internet connection and mining to a pool from these machines, it seems as though my internet connection has become a lot slower and a lot of data has been used up.

It's possible that this is simply an issue with my ISP, but I wanted to find out if anyone knows the amount of data uploaded/downloaded when hosting a full node and when mining now that RingCT has been implemented. Have bandwidth and data transfer requirements increased?

I'm aware of the 'limit' command in monerod, which I have set to 100, but sometimes it still seems like the Monero nodes and mining processes are taking up a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Spam account? Identical wording like: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/has-bandwidth-usage-or-data-transferred-when-mining-or-hosting-a-full-node-incre